# With Text File Create List then use List to Scrape from Webpage to create dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, web-scraping

I have a text file that has a list of hostnames:

```
router-1
firewall-1
firewall-2
distro-1
```

What I would like to do is create a list from that file, then from that list web scrape for certain a certain text string to determine the device's `device_platform`. Then with that create a dictionary that would look something like this:

```py
[
    {'hostname': 'router-1', 'device_platform': 'cisco_ios'},
    {'hostname': 'firewall-1', 'device_platform': 'juniper'},
    {'hostname': 'firewall-2', 'device_platform': 'cisco_asa'},
    {'hostname': 'distro-1', 'device_platform': 'broadcom_icos'}
]
```

So far this is what I have, the web scraping portion works. I just need to know how to add a part to create the list then from that list scrape the info and return it to create a dictionary like the one above.

```py
import requests
import urllib3


with open('devices.txt', 'r') as f:
    host = f.read().splitlines()
    print(host)
    for device in host:
        url = f'http://nunya.com/device/{device}.nunya.com/config'
        urllib3.disable_warnings()
        request = requests.get(url).text
        if 'event manager applet' in request and 'pager' not in request:
            device_platform = 'cisco_ios'
        elif 'junos' in request:
            device_platform = 'juniper'
        elif 'pager' in request:
            device_platform = 'cisco_asa'
        else:
            device_platform = 'broadcom_icos'
        print(f'hostname: {device}, device_platform: {device_platform}')
```

Comment: Is your question, how to create a list from the hostnames in the text file?

Comment: My end goal is to create a dictionary like the one shown in the question. I was thinking that creating a list first would be the place to start, then from that list do the web scraping then from the info gathered create a dictionary where each item in the list is value for the key `hostname`, and the returned info from the web scrape is the value for the key `device_platform`.

Comment: The answer below will create the list, you could then use that for your requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that what you want in the end is of this format,

```
[
    {'hostname': 'router-1', 'device_platform': 'cisco_ios'},
    {'hostname': 'firewall-1', 'device_platform': 'juniper'},
    {'hostname': 'firewall-2', 'device_platform': 'cisco_asa'},
    {'hostname': 'distro-1', 'device_platform': 'broadcom_icos'}
]
```

This is a `list` of `dictionaries` and not much change is required to your code to get this.

Just initiate an empty `list` before the `for` loop starts and keep appending the required `dictionaries` to it as the loop progresses. Here is the code:

```
import requests
import urllib3


with open('devices.txt', 'r') as f:
    host = f.read().splitlines()
    print(host)
    data = []
    for device in host:
        url = f'http://nunya.com/device/{device}.nunya.com/config'
        urllib3.disable_warnings()
        request = requests.get(url).text
        if 'event manager applet' in request and 'pager' not in request:
            device_platform = 'cisco_ios'
        elif 'junos' in request:
            device_platform = 'juniper'
        elif 'pager' in request:
            device_platform = 'cisco_asa'
        else:
            device_platform = 'broadcom_icos'
        data.append({'hostname': device, 'device_platform': device_platform})
        print(f'hostname: {device}, device_platform: {device_platform}')
    print(data)
```

As you can see, I am initiating an empty `list` by saying `data=[]` and inside the loop you can see that I am appending `dictionaries` with the required data to the list in the line `data.append({'hostname': device, 'device_platform': device_platform})`.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: If I wanted my dictionary to be formatted like this: `data = {'router1': {'device_platform': 'cisco_ios'}, 'firewall-1': {'device_platform': 'juniper'}, 'firewall-2': {'device_platform': 'cisco_asa'}, 'distro-1': {'device_platform': 'broadcom_icos'}}` how would you do that?

Comment: Then you can initiate a dictionary, and add data to it. The line of code where you add data to the dictionary would look something like this

```
data[device]={'device_platform':device_platform}
```
The issue is that since `device` is the key here, repetitions will not be recorded.